# Assigning SELECT to UPDATE command after concatenating in MySql

Tags: mysql, concatenation, sql-update

I want to fill the password in user table by concatenating 4 char from user name and last 5 digits from the accountnumber in Employee table(another table)

I tried the below query,but it returns empty.

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=0;
UPDATE user set password = (SELECT (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(user.username,1,4), SUBSTRING(employee.accountnumber,-5))) FROM employee WHERE user.employeename= employee.employeename);
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES=1;
```

When i tried SELECT statement seperately in editor,it returns exact values.

```
SELECT (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(user.username,1,4), SUBSTRING(employee.accountnumber,-5))) as pwd
FROM employee ,user WHERE user.employeename= employee.employeename;

xxxx03332
yyyy07674
```

But in UPDATE statement it is not working,as im setting password column as 'NOT NULL' option.when i execute in editor it shows error as *Error Code: 1048. Column 'password' cannot be null*
I tried below query,but same error

```
UPDATE user password , (SELECT (CONCAT(SUBSTRING(user.username,1,4), SUBSTRING(employee.accountnumber,-5))) FROM employee WHERE user.employeename= employee.employeename);
```

If i include 'user'(table name) in FROM clause,it shows error as *Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'user' for update in FROM clause*
So, i deleted that in UPDATE Statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why so complicated? Do it like this:

```
UPDATE user u
JOIN   employee e ON u.employeename = e.employeename
SET    u.password = Concat(Substring(u.username, 1, 4),
                          Substring(e.accountnumber, -5)) 
;
```